# imageJPEG() not working on online server

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I am fairly new to codeigniter and have reached a still point at this error, apparrently, i was using the captcha helper of the codeigniter in a form, it was working great on my localhost, and still it is working, but when i uploaded the application site on the online server the following error appears:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function ImageJPEG() in .../system/helpers/captcha_helper.php on line 233

I have autoloaded the captcha helper in config file, the following is my index function:

```
public function index()
    {
        //vaildation un successful
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
        $path = './application/captcha/';
        $url = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/application/captcha/';

        $vals = array(
                'img_path' => $path,
                'img_url' => $url,
                'font_path' => './application/fonts/VeraSe.ttf',
                'img_width' => '150',
                'img_height' => 30,
                'expiration' => 7200
            );

        $img = create_captcha($vals);
        $x = $this->session->set_userdata('captcha', $img['word']); 

        $data['image'] = $img['image'];
        $data['captcha1'] = $img['word'];
        $this->load->view('signup', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said that this is working on your localhost, the problem is with your PHP version of  your server. Compare PHP version with the copy of code igniter version and your server php documentation.